# SQL Server 2005 Full Text Index, removed single digits form noise file, still not returning in search

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, full-text-indexing

I have a SQL Server 2005 and we're running a full text index on one of our tables. Users often want to search for kayak 2 or tent 4, basically searching for 2 person kayaks or 4 person tents.

I removed all of the single number digits form the ENU noise list and rebuilt the index.  It is still not returning searches for single digits.

Originally it was...

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE CONTAINS(description, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, kayak) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, 4)')
```

This is generated when multi-word phrases are entered into the search. I also stripped out the `FORMSOF INFLECTIONAL` and did a direct search on the values. I'm not returning anything with the number 4 in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I change 4 to 10 or any other two digit number it works great.  Only single numbers do not work.  The fact that these are in the noise file and then I deleted them implies that it should work after I rebuilt the index, but it definitely is not.   Also, we're actually running in compatibility mode (2k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql 2K5 there just isn't any way to search for a single digit.  I know it's not a phrase but it would be nice if numbers 0-9 were indexed so I could search them in FT searches.  I am going to have to work around it and just not allow single digits or work around it with simple but slower like statements and wildcards.